# Is setting image dimensions via div img class the same as img class

Tags: html, css, image

Trying to speed up my site and i run into the specify image dimensions to avoid reflow and repaints.

If i have images in divs with `<div class="class"> .class img {height: xxxpx; width: xxxpx;}`

Wouldn't that be the same as setting dimensions within `<img class="class"> .class {height: xxxpx; width: xxxpx;}`?

Just wondering if it works the same way as im getting the specify image dimensions warning in gtmetrix.

Comment: I think it should be the same, and first and second code effects image. But to keep them opitized you must save in optimized in PhotoShop.

Comment: You have to resize images on server side if you want to optimize them, otherwise both above have the same effect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is the same. And, you can ignore the warning from gtmetrix.

http://gtmetrix.com/specify-image-dimensions.html

> Page Speed currently only detects image dimensions that are specified
>   via the image attributes. If you are specifying the dimensions via
>   CSS, then you can safely ignore this recommendation.

Comment: What about width: auto; height: 100%;. How would this be perceived? Am i safe here?

Comment: Yes, I think that's fine too. The point of it is to prevent "reflows" of the page after the images are loaded. If your layout stays put during the entire loading process, you're good.